# Using WebView WebGL from Android emulator

Tags: android, webview, webgl

As I understand, WebGL is only supported in WebView in Android Lollipop (updating the WebView component in the Play Store), and newer versions (no Play Store update required).

However, I have an emulator using Android 7.1.1, and WebGL is not working. http://webglreport.com says *"This browser supports WebGL 1, but it is disabled or unavailable."*. I have also tried an Android 6.0 emulator, with the same result.

WebGL works fine in the emulator when using Chrome, but not in a WebView.

WebGL works fine in a WebView in a physical 6.0 phone.

What could be the reason why WebGL is not working in the same emulator, when using a WebView?

Answer (score 5):

This turns out to be a limitation of the current version of the emulator: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229984

Comment: what about the new version now that it's years later?

Comment: I haven't tested it in recent times, apologies.